# jQuery not sending form correctly

Tags: jquery, forms, post, get

Everytime I submit this form, instead of it POSTing to the server, for some reason it re-loads the page and adds all the data as a GET

I was wondering if anyone see an error in the following code.

```
$("#updatebusiness").live('click', function(event){

        var tradingname = $('#tradingname').attr('value');
        var website     = $('#website').attr('value');
        var address     = $('#address').attr('value');
        var phonenumber = $('#phonenumber').attr('value');
        var email       = $('#email').attr('value');
        var postcode    = $('#postcode').attr('value');
        var state   = $('#state').val();
        var city    = $('#city').attr('value');
        var leadstatus  = $('#leadstatus').val();

        var sendemail   = $('#sendemail').val();
        var whichemail  = $('#whichemail').val();

        var notes       = $("#notes").val();
        var description     = $("#description").val();


        var callback    = $('#callback').val();
        var callbackdate    = $('#callbackyear').val()+"-"+$('#callbackmonth').val()+"-"+$('#callbackday').val();
        var callbacktime    = $('#callbackhour').val()+":"+$('#callbackmin').val();

        var companyname =   $('#companyname').attr('value');
        var acnabn      =   $('#acnabn').attr('value');
        var position    =   $('#position').attr('value');
        var title       =   $('#title').val();
        var firstname   =   $('#firstname').attr('value');
        var lastname    =   $('#lastname').attr('value');
        var industry    =   $('#industry').val();
        var subcategory =   $('#subcategory').val();
        var suburb1     =   $('#suburb1').attr('value');
        var suburb2     =   $('#suburb2').attr('value');
        var suburb3     =   $('#suburb3').attr('value');
        var suburb4     =   $('#suburb4').attr('value');
        var suburb5     =   $('#suburb5').attr('value');
        var suburb6     =   $('#suburb6').attr('value');
        var ms1         =   $('#ms1').attr('value');
        var ms2         =   $('#ms2').attr('value');
        var ms3         =   $('#ms3').attr('value');
        var ms4         =   $('#ms4').attr('value');
        var rcb1        =   $('#rcb1').attr('value');
        var rcb2        =   $('#rcb2').attr('value');
        var rcb3        =   $('#rcb3').attr('value');
        var rcb4        =   $('#rcb4').attr('value');
        var hotofferone =   $('#hotoffer1').attr('value');
        var hotofferrcb =   $('#hotofferrcb').attr('value');

        var hotofferstartdate   = $('#startday').val()+"-"+$('#startmonth').val()+"-"+$('#startyear').val();
        var hotofferfinishdate  = $('#finishday').val()+"-"+$('#finishmonth').val()+"-"+$('#finishyear').val();

        var terminalid  =   $('#terminalid').val();
        var bankname    =   $('#bankname').attr('value');
        var bsb         =   $('#bsb').attr('value');
        var cardtype    =   $('#cardtype').attr('value');
        var cardexpire  = $('#cardmonth').val()+"/"+$('#cardyear').val();

        if($('#terminalverified').is(':checked')) {
        var terminalverified    = "Yes";
        } else {
        var terminalverified    = "No";
        }

        var mobilenumber    =   $('#mobilenumber').attr('value');
        var faxnumber   =   $('#faxnumber').attr('value');
        var membershiptype  =   $('#membershiptype').attr('value');
        var keywords    =   $('#keywords').attr('value');
        var merchantid  =   $('#merchantid').attr('value');
        var bacname     =   $('#bacname').attr('value');
        var bacnumber   =   $('#bacnumber').attr('value');
        var crnumber    =   $('#crnumber').attr('value');
        var cvv         =   $('#cvv').attr('value');
        var incardallocation    =   $('#incardallocation').attr('value');


        var postaladdress   = $("#postaladdress").attr('value');
        var postalcity      = $("#postalcity").attr('value');
        var postalstate     = $("#postalstate").attr('value');
        var postalcode      = $("#postalcode").attr('value');
        var AMStatus        = $("#AMStatus").attr('value');

        if(usertype == 3 || usertype == 1)
        {
        var chosenusername      = $("#chosenusername").attr('value');
        var chosenpassword      = $("#chosenpassword").attr('value');
        }
        else
        {
        var chosenusername      = null;
        var chosenpassword      = null;
        }

        if(usertype == 1)
        {
        var leadowner   = $("#leadowner").val();
        }
        else
        {
        var leadowner   = $userid;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "system/classes/core.php",
            data: "task=updatebusinesslead&tradingname="+encodeURIComponent(tradingname)+"&website="+website+"&address="+address+"&phonenumber="+phonenumber+"&email="+email+"&postcode="+postcode+"&city="+city+"&state="+state+"&leadstatus="+leadstatus+"&sendemail="+sendemail+"&whichemail="+whichemail+"&callback="+callback+"&callbackdate="+callbackdate+"&callbacktime="+callbacktime+"&userid="+leadowner+"&companyname="+encodeURIComponent(companyname)+"&acnabn="+acnabn+"&position="+position+"&title="+title+"&firstname="+firstname+"&lastname="+lastname+"&industry="+industry+"&subcategory="+subcategory+"&suburbone="+suburb1+"&suburbtwo="+suburb2+"&suburbthree="+suburb3+"&suburbfour="+suburb4+"&suburbfive="+suburb5+"&suburbsix="+suburb6+"&msone="+ms1+"&mstwo="+ms2+"&msthree="+ms3+"&msfour="+ms4+"&rcbone="+rcb1+"&rcbtwo="+rcb2+"&rcbthree="+rcb3+"&rcbfour="+rcb4+"&hotofferone="+hotofferone+"&hotofferrcb="+hotofferrcb+"&hotofferstartdate="+hotofferstartdate+"&hotofferfinishdate="+hotofferfinishdate+"&terminalid="+terminalid+"&bankname="+bankname+"&bsb="+bsb+"&cardtype="+cardtype+"&cardexpire="+cardexpire+"&terminalverified="+terminalverified+"&mobilenumber="+mobilenumber+"&faxnumber="+faxnumber+"&membershiptype="+membershiptype+"&keywords="+keywords+"&merchantid="+merchantid+"&bacname="+encodeURIComponent(bacname)+"&bacnumber="+bacnumber+"&crnumber="+crnumber+"&cvv="+cvv+"&incardallocation="+incardallocation+"&postaladdress="+postaladdress+"&postalcity="+postalcity+"&postalstate="+postalstate+"&postalcode="+postalcode+"&notes="+encodeURIComponent(notes)+"&description="+encodeURIComponent(description)+"&chosenusername="+chosenusername+"&chosenpassword="+chosenpassword+"&AMStatus="+AMStatus+"&usertype="+usertype,
            success: function(data){
                if((data) == 1)
                {
                    loadadminlayout();
                //  alert(data);
                }
                else
                {
                alert(data);    
                }
            }
        });
        //continuebusinesslead();
return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you see any script errors in Firebug?

Comment: You're doing this the hard way. Take a look at [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: @thirtydot Exactly! See my post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever tried using jQuery's build in $.post() method?

you could easily shrink the code down to:

```
$("#updatebusiness").live('click', function(event){
$.post("system/classes/core.php", $("#your-form-id").serialize(), function(data) {
if((data) == 1) {
loadadminlayout();
//  alert(data);
}
else
{
alert(data);    
}
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, no I did not even know about this

Answer (score 0):

Is your $("#updatebusiness") an plain link (`<a href="#" id="updatebusiness">` the user has to click? If yes then you should add and [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the browser from going anywhere, or rather use a `<button>` instead.

also: try .serialize() instead!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a POST .ajax is expecting the "data" property of the object you are passing it. You are setting the method to post and then setting up the url you are posting to as a get. You need to serialize your form and assign it to the data property or you need to change your ajax type to "GET"